# does xk6-file support to delete a row from csv file?

Tags: k6

I am using the xk6-file read and write for csv files in my k6. I want to know that does this xk6-file can use for delete a row from csv?

Reference:    https://github.com/avitalique/xk6-file

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the README file it looks like it can overwrite files with arbitrary strings. k6 already provides [`open` in its JavaScript API](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/init-context/open-filepath-mode/) to read files.

Subsequently, it should be possible to read a file, modify the content, and then write the modified content back to the file.

Have you tried to modify your CSV file? Did you run into any specific problem(s)? Writing two lines of k6 test script probably does not take longer than asking this question here. If you encountered problems, please let us know about them so that we can give effective answers.